# Should CBPeripheralManager send data on a separate thread?

Tags: ios, concurrency, core-bluetooth

I am designing an iOS app in which users can send data via bluetooth. This is my first time using Bluetooth in an app, and I am wondering about best practices with it, particularly whether data transfer should be handled in a separate thread.

Once the `CBPeripheralManager` connects to a subscribing `CBCentralManager`, the loop that sends data boils down to:

```
while (didSend) {
    NSData *blob = /* some data */
    didSend = [self.manager updateValue:blob
                      forCharacteristic:self.characteristic
                   onSubscribedCentrals:nil]
}
```

If this executes on the main thread, does this necessarily mean that the user loses control of the app? For example, if a user then wants to cancel the transaction by closing the app or something, will I be able to tell the `CBPeripheralManager` to abort some way, or will I have to wait until the loop finishes? And if the latter is true, what is the best way to get around this issue?

Comment: Bluetooth LE wasn't designed for large amounts of data like that, so the loop will probably finish instantly and you have no way of viewing progress or cancelling for that matter... Do you have to use Bluetooth LE or can you use something like GKSession, Bonjour over Bluetooth (and WiFi), or something like that?

Comment: I haven't been developing long, so I'm not familiar with those alternatives. I'll look into them, though. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: I reimplemented it using GKSession. It is compatible with more devices now (which is good), but I'm still not sure how concurrency fits into the data transfer: whether it is already used, or should be used by me, etc. I guess I'll play around a bit and figure it out.